# Skill-Based Routing Backlog Showing Wrong Skills

Tags: servicecloud, omnichannel, skill-based-routing

This is what my skills backlog summary looks like:
[image]

But each of the records should only show one skill each, as it is based on a picklist field. This is what my skill map looks like:
[image]

I'm sure I have something wrong, but I cannot figure out what. As it is, when I go online in omni-channel, none of the records will get routed to me unless I have every single skill, when I should only need one.

For example, the "Queue Level" for Record "Cpy Brnz" is "Copywriter Bronze", and I have the Copywriter Bronze skill on my agent resource.

Comment: I was able to figure it ou! I had populated the 'skills' option under 'Routing Configuration' which I thought determined which skills would be routed, which is not the case. The 'Skills' option sets default skills that will attach to every record run through it.